# Got issue with upload and resize image in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
 var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    formidable = require('formidable'),
    util = require('util'),
    fs   = require('fs-extra'),
    qt   = require('quickthumb');

// Use quickthumb
app.use(qt.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.post('/upload', function (req, res){
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('received upload:\n\n');
    res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
  });

  form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
    /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
    var temp_path = this.openedFiles[0].path;
    /* The file name of the uploaded file */
    var file_name = this.openedFiles[0].name;
    /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
    var new_location = 'uploads/';

    fs.copy(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function(err) {  
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log("success!")
      }
    });
  });
});

// Show the upload form 
app.get('/', function (req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  var form = '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">Add a title: <input name="title" type="text" /><br><br><input multiple="multiple" name="upload" type="file" /><br><br><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></form>';
  res.end(form); 
}); 
app.listen(8080);
```

I am a fresher on node js and express js. I followed this [guy's blog](https://tonyspiro.com/uploading-resizing-images-fly-node-js-express/) to upload and resize image. The above is the code part. The upload function is working. However, in terms of resize function, if I want to resize uploaded image, I got this error:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn identify ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install `imagemagick`? Quickthumb requires it for work.

Comment: After run npm i imagemagick, I got imagemagick@0.1.3 imagemagick. I believe I did that.

Comment: @OtakuFitness No, it didn't.  According to documentation you must install imagemagic as util, e.g. `apt-get install imagemagick` on Linux. The error you got is that `quickthumb` cannot find program for `spawn`. Keep in mind that it just a wrapper for `imagemagic` so you have to install `imagemagic` itself.

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/zivester/node-quickthumb documentation (you use that lib)? Most probably the error is that `imagemagic` is not installed. Just make sure you have installed `imagemagic` and it in your PATH. If it isn't, fix it. If this wouldn't work let me know

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using win10 and vs2015 to do this, I installed imagemagick but the problem is still there, seems vs2015 didn't realised I installed imagemagick.

Comment: It doesn't matter what VS realize. Your application is executing with nodejs. Check PATH variable to sure imagemagic directory presents. If it doesn't add it  http://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: I installed imagemagic but the problem is still there. I didn't get the point of environment variable. What should I do after installed imagemagic?

Comment: Well, `quickthumb` uses `imagemagick` node modules. As we can see at  https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick/blob/master/imagemagick.js#L255 this lib spawns imagemagic convert tool http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php (it has call by name). So id you want get it to work you have to make sure that convert is intalled and available to called by name. To check it just open windows cmd and type `convert -version`. If all are correct you will see convert version info. Otherwise you should properly change PATH